# Reference an assembly from Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have a class library project in TFS version control. I want another project reference the output dll. Is there an easier way other then checking out the project and referencing the local copy? The class library will be updated pretty often.

Using Vs.net and TFS 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in the same team project, the best way to do this is through a project reference.  That way, it will just build both when it needs to.  If you don't want to do that, you will need to do a "get" of that DLL  prior to starting the build.

My suggestion would be to put in a pre-build event that does a `TF.exe get` to get the latest version of the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with hintpaths in your project to add local paths to the list of paths to search for assemblies